Powershell how to find a specific word in a string
I'm trying to write a powershell script where I have variable where for example it could be "Hellobrian" and I only want to check if the string contains "Hello". It is not as simple as split it in to two words, because I'm only looking to see if the string contains specific a word. Now I have tried
$contains = $myValue.Contains("Hello") and the other way of writing it -contains and the find method. Nothing works, I either get nothing or false.
Is there a way of checking for a specific word inside a string like this?

You can use -like and the wildcard character * (meaning any number of any character). e.g.
$src = "Hellobrian" 

if($src -like "*hello*"){
    write-host "Yup, it contains hello";
}

FYI Contains is case sensitive, so:

$src.Contains("Hello") ## <-- returns true
$src.Contains("hello") ## <-- returns false

NOTE: if your using PowerShell 7 then $src.Contains("hello", 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase') will perform a case in-sensitive match so will also work.

Update following comment:
Works exactly the same, eg
$src = "Hellobrian" 
$searchStr = "*hello*"

if($src -like $searchStr){
    write-host "Yup, it contains hello";
}


Thanks, how would like work if the other side was a variable? Say "Hello" was in a variable called $hello, could you still do $src -like $hello with wildcards?
